# Is it possible to use a bound value in ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

Is it possible to do the following:

```
<li><a ng-click="letterFilter = {section:'{{bound.value}}'}">{{bound.value}}</a></li>
```

to get the following output using ng-repeat and a JSON file to supply the data via $http

```
 <li><a ng-click="letterFilter = {section:'A'}">A</a></li>
 <li><a ng-click="letterFilter = {section:'B'}">B</a></li>
```

Thanks

Additional Information:
JSON

```
[{"section": "A"},{"section": "B"},{"section": "C"}]
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-controller="letterController" class="pagination">
    <li ng-repeat="letter in letters"><a ng-click="letterFilter = {section: letter.section}">{{letter.section}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
.controller('letterController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.letters= data;
      })
    }])
```

Comment: Can you provide the context for the binding variables?  For example, please show the `ng-repeat` and provide some sample objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-click` evaluates an [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so just reference the variable directly without the `{{ }}`.  For example:

```
<a ng-click="letterFilter = { 'section': bound.value }">{{bound.value}}</a>
```